# Why does Internet Explorer not support bookmarks with both a querystring and a hash/anchor? Firefox works properly

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, bookmarks

I am using anchor-bookmarks to move to the top, middle or bottom of the page when the page loads.
EG: `<a name="mid"></a>`

Now, when I simply pass an anchor-bookmark(#) in my URL then it is working perfectly in both IE and FF browsers.
EG: `http://.../Test.aspx#mid`

But, if I pass the same anchor-bookmark(#) along with any querystring in my URL then its NOT WORKING in IE. FF works fine.
EG: `http://.../Test.aspx?a=b&c=d#mid`

WHY is it not working with IE?

Answer (score 0):

Bug. RFC3986 shows it's perfectly OK: `foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose`

Comment: The internet standard for URI's.