# What is RFC3986?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, bookmarks

What is RFC3986?

In reference to the answer of my question [Why does Internet Explorer not support bookmarks with both a querystring and a hash/anchor? Firefox works properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703749/why-internet-explorer-does-not-support-hash-anchor-bookmark-along-with-queryst)

Answer (score 6):

A bit of googleing would have answered this for you pretty quickly.

RCF 3986 is the specification for URI syntax. An example of things which it defines is the `%` syntax for escaped characters in a URL.

In the context of the previous question which you referenced, the answer is stating that the RFC specification states that the syntax that you're using is valid, and therefore what you've discovered is a fault with IE. (this doesn't really help you, because you still need to support IE and live with its bugs, but at least you know it's IE's fault and not yours)

By the way, "RFC" stands for "Request for comments"; the sequence of numbered RFCs are the published specifications for most internet-related standards.

Wikipedia has a [fairly in-depth article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), which details the history and how this RFC relates to previous ones.

And here is the actual spec document in detail: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

Comment: I know that all, I just wanted to know how it is related to the answer for my question 
In reference to the answer of my question Why Internet Explorer does not support #(hash/anchor-bookmark) along with querystring? where FireFox is working properly.

Comment: @Hemang - see the edits I put in to tell you how it relates in the context of your previous question. Note: you say you 'know all that', but you didn't make it clear in your question what you knew.

Answer (score 1):

It's the **Request for Comments** (RFC) for URI: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

Check the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments) for more info.