# http://localhost:8080/@%7B/author/(id=1)%7D

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Please tell me why when I click on the link:

```
<td> <a href="@{/author/(id=${book.id})}"  type="button">Перейти</a></td>
```

I get the address in the url : http://localhost:8080/@%7B/author/(id=1)%7D?

The form that opens by clicking on the link: form action="@{/author/(id=${book.id})}" method="get"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<a href= "@{/author/${book.id}}" type="button"></a>
```

Comment: Does not work. Error : Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Answer (score 0):

```
href="/author/${book.id}"
```

Answer (score 0):

> **why** when I click on the link

The URL specified in template is `@{/author/(id=${book.id})}`.

`${book.id}` is resolved to `1` by Thymeleaf as this notation is consistent with Thymeleaf schema. Now, Spring URL resolver would see the final URL as `@{/author/(id=1)}`.

Spring follows [RFC3986](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704273/what-is-rfc3986) for encoding and decoding URLs.

URI percent encoding of `{` is `%7B`.
URI percent encoding of `}` is `%7D`.

Hence, Spring will encode `@{/author/(id=1)}` to `@%7B/author/(id=1)%7D`.

This is the reason why `@{/author/(id=${book.id})}` in your template translates to `@%7B/author/(id=1)%7D` for you.