# Open a multi open accordion tab and scroll to a hash location within that section (IE scrolling to hash anchor before evaluating query string?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, anchor

How can I create links that will expand a particular accordion section **and then scroll to a particular DIV within that section?**

I'm using the latest jQuery UI library as well as jquery.multi-accordion-1.5.3.js, and developing for IE8 or later

I've been able to successfully implement both multiAccordion and by parsing a query string I can manipulate which section to be expanded, and scroll to the first hash anchor.

*Strangely, this seems to work only for the first link, for any other link it scrolls past the corresponding hash anchor*, and overall it acts erratically.

I came across a few threads mentioning IE having issues recognizing hash anchors in a query string like this `index.php?page=page1#section3` , ie...[Why does Internet Explorer not support bookmarks with both a querystring and a hash/anchor? Firefox works properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703749/why-internet-explorer-does-not-support-hash-anchor-bookmark-along-with-querys) but I have not come across one solution...

Has anyone have a solution for this? Any alternatives?

Here is my code (or if it's more legible for you - the fiddle with the same code http://jsfiddle.net/3QSmq/1/)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery UI Multi Open Accordion</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.multi-accordion-1.5.3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    /*demo page css*/
    body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<a href="index.html?page=tab2#something">SOMETHING</a><br />
<a href="index.html?page=tab3#something1">SOMETHING1</a>
<div id="multiAccordion">
    <h3><a href="#" id="tab1">tab 1</a></h3>
    <div>Text here
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#" id="tab2">tab 2</a></h3>
    <div>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu mauris nulla, at cursus nulla. Morbi venenatis, risus sit amet ultricies pharetra, lorem purus tempor risus, vel tincidunt lectus nisi sit amet neque. Aenean sit amet nibh orci, a gravida eros. Pellentesque dignissim, libero eu congue semper, mauris metus molestie nisi, vitae posuere felis leo ac lectus. Mauris a nisi eget sapien varius eleifend vel vel nibh. In placerat commodo blandit. Vivamus sagittis ante sed nisl sodales id luctus diam dapibus. Proin a felis tristique nulla rhoncus sollicitudin. Nullam sit amet neque augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce at nisi sapien.
    <p id="something" style="color:red">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu mauris nulla, at cursus nulla. Morbi venenatis, risus sit amet ultricies pharetra, lorem purus tempor risus, vel tincidunt lectus nisi sit amet neque. Aenean sit amet nibh orci, a gravida eros. Pellentesque dignissim, libero eu congue semper, mauris metus molestie nisi, vitae posuere felis leo ac lectus. Mauris a nisi eget sapien varius eleifend vel vel nibh. In placerat commodo blandit. Vivamus sagittis ante sed nisl sodales id luctus diam dapibus. Proin a felis tristique nulla rhoncus sollicitudin. Nullam sit amet neque augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce at nisi sapien.
    </p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu mauris nulla, at cursus nulla. Morbi venenatis, risus sit amet ultricies pharetra, lorem purus tempor risus, vel tincidunt lectus nisi sit amet neque. Aenean sit amet nibh orci, a gravida eros. Pellentesque dignissim, libero eu congue semper, mauris metus molestie nisi, vitae posuere felis leo ac lectus. Mauris a nisi eget sapien varius eleifend vel vel nibh. In placerat commodo blandit. Vivamus sagittis ante sed nisl sodales id luctus diam dapibus. Proin a felis tristique nulla rhoncus sollicitudin. Nullam sit amet neque augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce at nisi sapien.

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu mauris nulla, at cursus nulla. Morbi venenatis, risus sit amet ultricies pharetra, lorem purus tempor risus, vel tincidunt lectus nisi sit amet neque. Aenean sit amet nibh orci, a gravida eros. Pellentesque dignissim, libero eu congue semper, mauris metus molestie nisi, vitae posuere felis leo ac lectus. Mauris a nisi eget sapien varius eleifend vel vel nibh. In placerat commodo blandit. Vivamus sagittis ante sed nisl sodales id luctus diam dapibus. Proin a felis tristique nulla rhoncus sollicitudin. Nullam sit amet neque augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce at nisi sapien.

    </div>
    <h3><a href="#" id="tab3">tab 3</a></h3>
    <div>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu mauris nulla, at cursus nulla. Morbi venenatis, risus sit amet ultricies pharetra, lorem purus tempor risus, vel tincidunt lectus nisi sit amet neque. Aenean sit amet nibh orci, a gravida eros. Pellentesque dignissim, libero eu congue semper, mauris metus molestie nisi, vitae posuere felis leo ac lectus. Mauris a nisi eget sapien varius eleifend vel vel nibh. In placerat commodo blandit. Vivamus sagittis ante sed nisl sodales id luctus diam dapibus. Proin a felis tristique nulla rhoncus sollicitudin. Nullam sit amet neque augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce at nisi sapien.
    <p id="something1" style="color:red">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu mauris nulla, at cursus nulla. Morbi venenatis, risus sit amet ultricies pharetra, lorem purus tempor risus, vel tincidunt lectus nisi sit amet neque. Aenean sit amet nibh orci, a gravida eros. Pellentesque dignissim, libero eu congue semper, mauris metus molestie nisi, vitae posuere felis leo ac lectus. Mauris a nisi eget sapien varius eleifend vel vel nibh. In placerat commodo blandit. Vivamus sagittis ante sed nisl sodales id luctus diam dapibus. Proin a felis tristique nulla rhoncus sollicitudin. Nullam sit amet neque augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce at nisi sapien.
    </p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu mauris nulla, at cursus nulla. Morbi venenatis, risus sit amet ultricies pharetra, lorem purus tempor risus, vel tincidunt lectus nisi sit amet neque. Aenean sit amet nibh orci, a gravida eros. Pellentesque dignissim, libero eu congue semper, mauris metus molestie nisi, vitae posuere felis leo ac lectus. Mauris a nisi eget sapien varius eleifend vel vel nibh. In placerat commodo blandit. Vivamus sagittis ante sed nisl sodales id luctus diam dapibus. Proin a felis tristique nulla rhoncus sollicitudin. Nullam sit amet neque augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce at nisi sapien.



    </div>
    <h3><a href="#" id="tab4">tab 4</a></h3>
    <div>Text Here
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
        $('#multiAccordion').multiAccordion({
            active: [1, 2],
            click: function(event, ui) {
                //console.log('clicked')
            },
            init: function(event, ui) {
                //console.log('whoooooha')
            },
            tabShown: function(event, ui) {
                //console.log('shown')
            },
            tabHidden: function(event, ui) {
                //console.log('hidden')
            }

        });

        $('#multiAccordion').multiAccordion("option", "active", [y]);
    });

    function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");

   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);


}
var x = getQueryVariable("page");

switch (x){
        case(x = "tab1"):
        y = 0;
        break;  
        case(x = "tab2"):
        y = 1;
        break;          
        case(x = "tab3"):
        y = 2;
        break;          
        case(x = "tab4"):
        y = 3;
        break;
        case(x = false):
        y = "";
        break;
        default:
        y ="";
        break;
        }
```

Any suggestions?

P.S. Here is THE closest description of my issue elsewhere on the web but no answer..[.Another thread](http://www.cre8asiteforums.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=35100)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of including the tab with the page, just target the ID from the hash. So your links will look like this:

```
<a href="#something">SOMETHING</a><br />
<a href="#something1">SOMETHING1</a>
```

Then you can include this code to find the ID from the hash, find the correct tab and open it. Here is the complete code & [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/3QSmq/2/):

```
$(function() {

    var updateAccordion = function(hash) {
        hash = hash || window.location.hash;
        var content, tab;
        // look for a hash
        if (hash && $(hash).length) {
            // find accordion content
            content = $(hash).closest('.ui-accordion-content');
            if (content.length) {
                // find "tab#" from <a> inside of accordion header (h3)
                tab = parseInt(content.prev('h3').find('a').attr('id').replace('tab',''), 10) - 1;
                $('#multiAccordion').multiAccordion("option", "active", [tab]);
            }
        }
    };

    // intercept all clicked links and look for a hash
    $('a').click(function(){
        if (this.hash) {
            updateAccordion(this.hash);
        }
    });

    $('#multiAccordion').multiAccordion({
        active: [1],
        click: function(event, ui) {
            //console.log('clicked')
        },
        init: function(event, ui) {
            //console.log('whoooooha')
        },
        tabShown: function(event, ui) {
            //console.log('shown')
        },
        tabHidden: function(event, ui) {
            //console.log('hidden')
        }
    });

    // open up accordion to correct tab after initialization
    updateAccordion();
});​
```

Comment: Your code provides a great alternative to controlling which tab to open using a hash but my issue still remains- the browser does not scroll to the y offset of that hash mark, it just opens the right tab. My problem seems to be with an IE bug (IE not able to take in the values from the parsed string in the correct order, updating my question)....so I'm starting to think about setting a pause after the switch is evaluated and then scrolling to the hash....

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.location.hash` to access directly the hash parameters.
In your example :

```
index.html?page=tab2#something
```

`document.location.search` will be `?page=tab2`

`document.location.hash` will be `#something`

You are trying to parse the wrong value, so I guess the JQuery plugin scroll to the bottom of the page when it's trying to open a tab that doesn't exists.

Comment: You are right, however, if I retrieve `document.location.has`h and set an alert right after it it becomes evident that the browser scrolls to it and only AFTER it has scrolled to the hash it executes the switch....